# Which Google Cloud Endpoints (Python) Client Library Jar to use in Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a Google Cloud Endpoints API I want to consume in Android Studio.  I created the Client Library, which is a zip file.

I'm in Step 4 of this document:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/clients/android/setup

They use Maven, and are referring to a JAR file in this path:

```
<your-path>/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-android/target/endpoints-client-libs/helloworld/target/helloworld-v1-1.17.0-rc-SNAPSHOT.jar

Make a note of this location so you know where to get the JAR file later when you configure your Android project.
```

However, my Python API required using endpointscfg.py instead.  The zip file has a different structure.

There are Jar files in the following folders:

```
<base path>/ - one JAR file
<base path>/libs/ - 28 JAR files
<base path>/libs-sources/ - 27 JAR files
```

There's no "target" folder, and no file ending in "-SNAPSHOT.jar"

Which one do I "Add as Library" into my Android Studio project, so that I can call my Google Cloud Endpoints (Python) API from Android?

Answer (score 1):

you need the one that contains your generated code, as well as the dependencies(in libs, which you don't already have in your android project).

Comment: Hi Ashish, how do I detect which ones contain my generated code?

Comment: unzip and check.  
<base path>/ - one JAR file